# Calling a method in a separate thread causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

i have a method loadDatabase(). The method itself works perfect.

When i create a separate thread and call the method loadDatabase() i get the error shown below.
On the main thread it works fine.

Any ideas?
Note: The values causecode,eventid and description are not null as i have printed them to the screen.

**Error**

```
15:59:58,693 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-64) Importing EcentCauseSheet
15:59:58,694 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-64) Cause Code is 0
15:59:58,694 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-64) Event Id  4097
15:59:58,695 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-64) Description is RRC CONN SETUP-SUCCESS
15:59:58,703 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-64) Exception in thread "Thread-64" java.lang.NullPointerException
15:59:58,704 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-64)     at com.testapp.service.EntryConfig.loadDatabase(EntryConfig.java:131)
15:59:58,704 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-64)     at com.testapp.service.EntryConfig.HelloWorld(EntryConfig.java:48)
15:59:58,704 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-64)     at com.testapp.service.EntryConfig.run(EntryConfig.java:39)
```

**Java Code for class**

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class EntryConfig extends Thread implements TableDao {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;
//.......
```

**Java Code for thread**

```
@Override
       public void run()
       {
        HelloWorld();

       }
```

public void HelloWorld()
    {

```
    try {
        loadDatabase();         

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Java Code for loadDatabase()**

```
public void loadDatabase()
    {
        InputStream inp = null;
        System.out.println("Eureka Kind of .....");
        try {   
            inp = new FileInputStream("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/test.xls");  

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Sheet eventCauseTableSheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);

            for (int i = 1; i <= eventCauseTableSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Importing EcentCauseSheet");

                row = eventCauseTableSheet.getRow(i);                                       
                int causeCode = (int)(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());                                         
                int eventId = (int)(row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());                      
                String description = row.getCell(2).toString();

                System.out.println("Cause Code is " + causeCode);
                System.out.println("Event Id  " + eventId);             
                System.out.println("Description is " + description);

                EventCauseTable eventCauseTable = new EventCauseTable(causeCode,eventId,description);               
                em.persist(eventCauseTable);
                System.out.println("Persisted EventCauseSheet row" + (i+1));

            }

//............
```

Comment: All the code in the finally block should be in the try block. And you should NOT ignore exceptions. Also, an EJB extending Thread looks like a serious design smell.

Comment: hi - so what could be the problem

Comment: The real problem is probably hidden by your catch(Exception){} block. Start by removing it, in order for the real exception to be logged, with a meaningful error message. And tell us which line is line 131, since this is where the exception happens.

Comment: line 131 is  em.persist(eventCauseTable);

Comment: So, what could be null in this line? eventCauseTable? Not possible, you initialize it just before. So, what's remaining?

Comment: thanks for the help - would it be possible for the entity manager to be somehow not initialized or empty? remember this works fine when not in a thread...

Comment: It's not only possible. It's absolutely sure. It is null, since calling a method on it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: would it have anything to do with the "@Stateful"
"@LocalBean" or something like this?

Comment: I don't know anything about you environment, but a stateful DAO looks suspicious. An EJB extending Thread is suspicious as well. And starting threads in an EJB looks very suspicious as well. And your exception handling is plain wrong. Don't you have anyone in your team able to help you? Injecting an entity manager in a DAO should be something tested at the very beginning of a project. And AFAIK, it must be done with the PersistenceContext annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a Thread in a stateful EJB is generally a bad idea, since it may be [passivated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html#gipln) by the container at any time. You could also think about clustering and SFSB replication - your EJB might be serialized to another machine, and a Thread isn't really applicable for this (it isn't [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)).

If your NullPointerException is thrown at em.persists(...), then you're missing the "em" reference. Most likely, you're trying to @Inject an EntityManager into an EntryConfig instance, that isn't managed by the container. If you want to reuse this class outside of the container, than you'll need to set the EntityManager manually (the first part still applies tough - you should probably redesign the whole component).